# Django queryset syntax using WHERE IN clause question

Tags: django

I could use assistance with a queryset call. Here are the models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    posterID = models.ForeignKey("User",  
      on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post")
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    timestamp =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Follow(models.Model):
    followerID = models.ForeignKey("User", 
       on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
       related_name="follower")
    followingID = models.ForeignKey("User", 
       on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
       related_name="follower_id")
```

I am trying to select all Post with a **posterID**
that are matching the **followingID** in Follow and are being followed (followerID) by the current user.

I believe my SQL should be as such:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Post
WHERE Post.posterID IN
 (
    SELECT followingID
    FROM Follow
    WHERE followerID = request.user.id
 )
```

I am guessing that I could start with something like:
(assuming that currently request.user id == 1)

```
f = Follow.objects.filter(followerID=1)
p = Post.objects.filter(posterID__in= [-- something 
    with f--] )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: `Post` and `Follow` aren't connected?

Comment: They are not connected and have to go through User as the middle man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get this done and it may not be the best way to do it, but it works.

```
// First I created a queryset from the Follow model:
    user = request.user
    f = Follow.objects.filter(followerID=user)

// Because the I need JUST the followingID from f, I created a list for it:
    fList = []

// Then I went iterated through the queryset, just appending the followingID to the list:
    for x in range(len(f)):
            fList.append(f[x].followingID)

// Finally I used the list in the main query from Post model:
    posts = Post.objects.filter(posterID__in=fList)
    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)
```